# Golang: Replace function unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm working with Golang, and currently I'm doing some fun unit test with [Testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify), my file look like this

```
type myStruct struct {
  field_1 string

}
func (self *myStruct) writeFirst()  {
//doing something
//modify field_1
self.writeSecond()
}

func (self *myStruct) writeSecond() {
//doing something
}
```

In this case I'm testing writeFirst() but I'm trying to replace writeSecond() because it is using http stuff that I don't want to use because it access to internet.

I think that use a second struct and set myStruct as anonymous field will be the solution, but it's not working because me second struct and myStruct have a diferent context.

In this case I can't use mocks cause  writeSecond is a method of the struct.

My test case looks like this:

```
func TestWriteFirst(t *testing.T) {
   myStc := myStruct{}
   assert.Equal(t,"My response", myStc.field_1)
}
```

All that I want is testing writeFirst without pass to writeSecond()

Comment: As far as I know, you can't, you'd have to use a flag or something to make `writeSecond` be ignored.

Comment: You'll have to refactor your code, making writeSecond some sort of interface you can mock and inject into the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate the kind of refactoring mentioned by [Not-a-Golfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239701/not-a-golfer) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791040/golang-replace-function-unit-testing/24796659#comment38477691_24791040), you could consider calling your second function only on an instance that is an interface:

```
type F2er interface {
    Func2()
}

type S struct{ _f2 F2er }

var s = &S{}

func (s *S) f2() F2er {
    if s._f2 == nil {
        return s
    }
    return s._f2
}

func (s *S) Func1() {
    fmt.Println("s.Func1")
    s.f2().Func2()
}
```

Here: `Func1` calls `Func2` on `s.f2()`, not directly `s`.

- If nothing has been set in `s`, `s.f2()` returns... itself: `s`
- if `s._f2` was replaced by any other `struct` which implements `Func2`, `s.f2()` returns that instance instead of itself.

See a complete example in this [playground script](http://play.golang.org/p/yaK7Vcs_nD).

Output:

```
TestFunc1
s.Func1
s.Func2

TestFunc1bis
s.Func1
testS.Func2    <=== different Func2 call
```